# jQuery, function within function targets wrong div

Tags: jquery, html, css, arrays, toggle

I have set of objects where I'm hiding `div` inside the wrapper, which alos has a child `<a>` button that toggles a slideDown-effect on the hidden object. However when clicked it opens only the hidden div in the last object, instead of only in ITS child

Simplified HTML:

```
<div class="panel-compressed">
  <div class="panel-header">
     <div class="toggle-panel">
       <a href="#" class="toggle-panel-btn">Open content</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
       <p>Content goes here</p>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-compressed">
  <div class="panel-header">
     <div class="toggle-panel">
       <a href="#" class="toggle-panel-btn">Open content</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
       <p>Content goes here</p>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-compressed">
  <div class="panel-header">
     <div class="toggle-panel">
       <a href="#" class="toggle-panel-btn">Open content</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body"> <!-- THIS OPENS WHEN CLICKING ANY .toggle-panel-btn -->
       <p>Content goes here</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $panelToggle = $('.toggle-panel-btn'); //Toggle button
var $panelBody = $('.panel-body'); //Hidden content
var $panelCompressed = $('.panel-compressed') //Wrapper

function togglePanel(){ 
         $this = $(this);
         $this.find($panelBody).hide();
        //Open .panel-body
        function showPB() {
            $this.find($panelBody).slideDown();
            $this.find($panelToggle).one("click", hidePB);
            $this.addClass('dropdown-open');
        }

        //close .panel-body
        function hidePB() {
            $this.find($panelBody).slideUp();
            $this.find($panelToggle).one("click", showPB);
            $this.removeClass('dropdown-open');
        }
        $this.find($panelToggle).click("click", showPB);
    }

    $panelCompressed.each(togglePanel);
```

Comment: When using `find` such as `$this.find($panelBody)` pass the selector like `$this.find('.panel-body')`

Comment: is this because the variable is outside the function?

Comment: it is because `var $panelBody = $('.panel-body');` outside the function finds ALL panelbodies, not just the you are looking for. For your code to hide you would need to loop over the $panelBody and find the parent that matched $(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is far too complex.

Here is a simpler one:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.panel-compressed .toggle-panel-btn').on("click",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // cancel link click
     $(this).closest(".panel-compressed")
       .toggleClass("dropdown-open")
       .find('.panel-body').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.panel-body { display:none }
.dropdown-open { background-color:pink }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-compressed">
  <div class="panel-header">
     <div class="toggle-panel">
       <a href="#" class="toggle-panel-btn">Open content</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
       <p>Content goes here</p>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-compressed">
  <div class="panel-header">
     <div class="toggle-panel">
       <a href="#" class="toggle-panel-btn">Open content</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
       <p>Content goes here</p>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-compressed">
  <div class="panel-header">
     <div class="toggle-panel">
       <a href="#" class="toggle-panel-btn">Open content</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body"> <!-- THIS OPENS WHEN CLICKING ANY .toggle-panel-btn -->
       <p>Content goes here</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers, thats obviously neater. I forgot that the slides aldready had a toggle-function :). However for me every `.panel-body` (maybe something with my html) below the element was toggled, changing .find to .children it:
`var $panelBody = $(this).closest('.panel-compressed').children('.panel-body').slideToggle();`

Comment: If the html is the same as you have posted, then find will work the same as children unless you have more than one body. I also added the class to the parent now

Answer (score 1):

```js
var $panelCompressed = $('.panel-compressed') //Wrapper

function togglePanel(){
     var $this = $(this);
     var $panelBody = $this.find('.panel-body').hide();
     var $panelToggle = $this.find('.toggle-panel-btn');
  
     //Toggle .panel-body
     function togglePB() {
         $panelBody.slideToggle();
         $this.toggleClass('dropdown-open');
     }

     $panelToggle.click(togglePB);
}

$panelCompressed.each(togglePanel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-compressed">
  <div class="panel-header">
     <div class="toggle-panel">
       <a href="#" class="toggle-panel-btn">Open content</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
       <p>Content goes here</p>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-compressed">
  <div class="panel-header">
     <div class="toggle-panel">
       <a href="#" class="toggle-panel-btn">Open content</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
       <p>Content goes here</p>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-compressed">
  <div class="panel-header">
     <div class="toggle-panel">
       <a href="#" class="toggle-panel-btn">Open content</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body"> <!-- THIS OPENS WHEN CLICKING ANY .toggle-panel-btn -->
       <p>Content goes here</p>
   </div>
</div>
```